# MySQL return the nearest higher value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of data as follows:

```
id    type     temp
01    ABC123   10
02    ABC123   20
03    ABC123   30
```

A user may supply a temp number of 18, so in this case I want to return 20, so the nearest higher temp value to that supplied. How do I do this please. I cannot find a matching answer / example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what result you want if user supply 20 ?

Comment: Have you got your satisfied answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(temp) 
FROM foo 
WHERE temp > &userinput;`
```

Comment: Long day, too easy. you guys rock! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Select * from table where temp>input order by temp limit 1`